# Publishing AWS Lambda .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I want to use AWS Lambda function. I created a sample AWS Lambda project (.net core 1) in Visual Studio 2017. I created a simple function and published it to AWS Lambda. It seems to be working when I press "Invoke" button. However, this function doesn't appear in AWS console. I wanted to set a timer (cron) when this function will be executed but I am not able to access it through AWS console.

```
public class Function
{
    public async Task<string> FunctionHandler()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://cb910302.ngrok.io/dashboard/test", null);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseString;
    }
}
```

I followed some tutorials (e.g. http://www.dotnetforall.com/publishing-running-net-core-aws-lambda/) but the lambda function just doesn't appear in my console after I publish it (even though the invoke button works and successfully executes the function). I googled that problem but it looks like no one had such problem which makes me feel that I am just missing a simple thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I thought the problem was in a region. I was just looking for a lambda function in a wrong region. Therefore, I couldn't find it.